# How to play you tube video in react-js without share option?

Tags: reactjs, youtube, youtubeplayer

I am trying to play some unlisted videos through my academy portal and only paid users can access it. But while I'm using you tube player it can share to anyone from a paid user. How I solve this issue..? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling sharing option from those private Youtube videos